# How to check if slideshow is running

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to check if slideshow is running. Here is my code:

```
private void checkSlideShow()
{
    if (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.Active == msoTrue)
    {
    //slideshow is running
    }
}
```

I get this error: `The name 'msoTrue' does not exist in the current context`

What is `msoTrue` and what I need to write here ... == ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write `MsoTriState.msoTrue` from http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms251168.